Can a proposition be possibly true and possibly false simultaneously?
Can anyone know '◊A and ◊not A', or using SQML can it be shown that it impossible for that statement to symbolize a true proposition?

You mean can it be true under actualism? ◊A ∧ ◊¬A is true for any contingent A, e.g. A = "space aliens exist".

If ◊A and ◊¬A couldn't both be true of the same A, then there would not be much point to modal logic.

@kaya3 You might want to reconsider your response, as the law of the excluded middle has an interesting relationship with modal semantics done in possible worlds and the general nature of a non-classic logic called dialethism.

Of course. How could the actual Question be about anything other than the meaning of the word possibly…'?

How about some people are asleep and some people are not asleep?

@MarcoOcram, that isn't a modal logical statement.  You need possibly or necessarily in the sentence.

I know- I was just stirring the pot. Cheers!

It's possible that Alice killed Bob, it's also possible that Alice did not kill Bob. Until we get more evidence, we don't know which of the possibilities is actually true (and we may never get sufficient evidence).


Can a proposition be possibly true and possibly false simultaneously?

Isn't that just obvious?
I guess it depends on what "possible" is taken to mean, and in this the imagination is the limit, but if we are reasonable, then if you don't know that p, then you have to accept that p is both possibly true and possibly false, just because you don't have any information excluding any one possibility.
Philosophers have invented different sorts of possibilities: Logical, metaphysical, physical etc. but all possibilities come down to logical possibility. Thus, in the absence of any assumption about p, p is both possibly true and possibly false. This much is logical.

If you believe that, then where is the error in my proof?

Can you elaborate on how all forms of possibility boil down to logical possibility? Are you saying that metaphysical possibility et al are definable in terms of logical possibility? Can you justify such a claim?

@PW_246 "Can you justify such a claim?" It is trivially true once you assume that humans are logical. If you assume they are not, or that it is unknown, then nothing I could say could convince you. Isn't that just obvious?

@Speakpigeon not at all, especially since I have no idea how you are using the term ‘logical possibility’.  If you mean satisfiability, then ok, but I have a feeling you don’t mean that.

@speakpigeon Also, humans just are not perfectly logical. You’re a perfect example of an illogical human.

@PW_246 "I have no idea how you are using the term ‘logical possibility’" Logical possibility is self-explaining, at least for logical people. 2. "satisfiability" I have no idea what that is. - 2. "humans just are not perfectly logical." Perfectly?! If it is logical, it is perfectly logical, so "perfectly" is just irrelevant. Humans of course are not entirely logical, if that's what you mean. Many parts of the human body don't have any logical capacity, but the brain certainly does. Anyway, this conversation has no point if you're not "perfectly" logical.

@Speakpigeon you’ve said that people are perfectly logical before, so don’t act surprised. if you don’t know what satisfiability means in logic, get off of your pedestal and start learning something real about Logic. The field didn’t stop when Russell discovered the paradox in Frege’s set theory. Satisfiability is the ability to make a sentence of some logic true in a given valuation of its positive literals. For example, “P or Q” is satisfied when “P” is satisfied, since we can show that the truth function “P or Q” outputs a 1 when P evaluates to 1.

@PW_246 "a sentence of some logic" Gobbledegook. - 2. "start learning something real about Logic."  Logic is a cognitive capacity, so we don't need to learn, we need to investigate. Logic is not in books. Textbooks are all crap. Anyway, you claim you're not "perfectly" logical, so you're not logical at all, so this conversation is a waste of time.

@Speakpigeon What? How does imperfect logic imply the incapacity to do logic or be logical? Stop being blatantly wrong.

@PW_246 "How does imperfect logic imply the incapacity to do logic or be logical?" I explained logically, so no wonder you don't understand. To understand what other people say, we need to be logical (or "perfectly" logical as you would put it).

@soeakpigeon No, you just stated your opinion with no justification, like you always do. Stop playing games.

@PW_246 You said humans are no perfectly logical, and I will guess that you are human, so according to you, you are not perfectly logical. But if one is not perfectly logical, one is not logical. So, according to you, you're not logical, so there is no point to this conversation.

@Speakpigeon “But if one is not perfectly logical, one is not logical.” How do you justify this? That’s my whole question. You’re inferring a general conclusion from a specific case without warrant.

@PW_246 "“But if one is not perfectly logical, one is not logical.” How do you justify this?" A figure which is not perfectly circular is not a circle. One counterexample is enough to falsify a general rule.

@speakpigeon That’s not even close to a good analogy. You’re saying if there is even one instance of illogical reasoning, then there is no logical reasoning on behalf of the one who was illogical. I guess in your case it’s true, but it’s not true for everyone.

Can a proposition be possibly true and possibly false simultaneously?
Yes. This answer does not involve modal logic, however.
On the Square of Opposition, the extremes are represented by the A and E statements: respectively, ‘All X’s are Y’s’ and ‘No X’s are Y’s’. A and E statements are contraries: both cannot be true at the same time, but both can be false at the same time.
The situation described in the question involves the subcontraries: both cannot be false at the same time, but both can be true at the same time. These are the I and O statements: ‘Some X’s are Y’s’ and ‘Some X’s are not Y’s.’
It is possible that Some and Some-not may be true simultaneously.
Comment after 3 downvotes: I have no edit to offer. This answer is correct.
Second comment.
The situation described in the posted question involves the subcontraries: both cannot be false at the same time, but both can be true at the same time. These are the I and O statements: ‘Some X’s are Y’s’ and ‘Some X’s are not Y’s.’
Why it matters. The square of opposition is analogous between the categorical statements and modal logic. Note that the  questions as posted and as described in the text are different. Both look at the statement '◊A and ◊not A’. The posted question asks if this relation can possibly be true. The text asks for proof that it is impossible for this relation to be true.This answer looks only at the initial post.
The I statement, ‘Some X’s are Y’s’ corresponds to ◊A, and the O statement, ‘Some X’s are not Y’s.’ corresponds to ◊not A. Which is to say that ◊A and ◊not A bear the same relationship to the statements about necessity as the I and O bear to their respective universal quantifiers, A and E.
It is possible for the two statements about possibility to be true simultaneously: “It is possible for X to be Y” and “It is possible for X to be not-Y.” Not necessary, just possible. Thus, the answer to the posted question is Yes, and the answer to the question in the text is No.
Sources:
Allow me to be, as far as I know, the first Philosophy Exchange Stacker to offer an AI-generated answer. From DuckAssist (DuckDuckGo) via ChatGPT:

The square of opposition is a diagram that represents the
relationships between four basic categorical propositions in logic. In
modal logic, it can be adapted to include modal terms, but the
traditional square primarily focuses on categorical propositions such
as universal affirmatives and negations.

There it is. That’s the straight skinny, from the Great Cloud itself. Unfortunately, the Cloud adds, “Responses may contain inaccuracies.” (Such fallacious reasoning is known as “The Appeal to Hallucinations.”)
The following sources are what allow me to say that this over here is just like that over there. More specifically, I argue that because of their similarities, the inference rules that apply to the traditional square also apply to the modal square.

“Two Standard and Two Modal Squares of Opposition Studied in Transparent Intensional Logic.” doc. PhDr. Jiří Raclavský, Ph.D. Department of Philosophy, Masaryk University, Brno.
https://www.esf.kfi.zcu.cz/logika/opory/pha0204/prezentace/prezentace_4_2014-TIL-slides-Square-of-Opposition.pdf

A search using the term, “modal logic square opposition”. Among the collection of retrieved images are several which arrange modal logic into the square of opposition. The citations include:
-https://www.researchgate.net/;
-slideserve.com, at pg 7 of12;
-https://www.mdpi.com/.

Many, many abstracts which (apparently) support my point, all of which lie peacefully behind a cursèd paywall, typically at SpringerLink. If your institution has a subscription, then conduct the search described in #2 above, and dive deep.


I want to add that I agree with the comment of @kaya3 to the original post.

I’m not sure why your answer got so many downvotes, but modality is quite clearly involved since it’s in the nature of the question, and though the diamond operator is like an existential quantifier, it’s not the same.

I'm not one of the downvoters, but I would have to say that your answer seems to me to be completely irrelevant to the question.

Based on Kristian Berry's response I decided to construct a proof that they can't be true simultaneously, and discovered a proof that they can be true simultaneously.
Let A be a specific statement.
Theorem: ∃A:◊A and ◊not A
Proof.

Not(∃A: ◊A and ◊not A)[OSC1]
∀A: not◊A or not◊not A[1;QN,DM]
∀A: ◻not A or ◻A[2;SQML]

The meaning of line 3 is that any proposition is necessarily true or necessarily false.  The statement "I am hungry" denotes a proposition that is neither necessarily true nor necessarily false,  therefore line 3 is false.

If ∀A: ◻not A or ◻A then contradiction.
Not(∀A: ◻not A or ◻A)[4;RAA]
∃A: not◻not A and not◻A[5;QN,DM]
∃A:◊A and ◊not A[SQML]

Q.E.D.
This proof suggests an interpretation for the words 'possible' and 'necessary'.  If a proposition is true and cannot change truth value it's necessary, and conversely.
◻A iff A is true and A cannot change truth value.
◊A iff A is true or A can change truth value.

Your proof is incorrect. Also you have misunderstood Kristian Berry's answer. His answer states that it is possible for ◊A and ◊¬A to be true. A model for ◊A and ◊¬A occurs when you have a base world w, accessible worlds u and v, A is true at u and ¬A is true at v.

@Bumble, if my proof is incorrect, where's the error?  There's only one world, all that mumbo gumbo about accessible worlds is wrong if there's only one world.

You cannot go from 6 to 7. You are trying to infer P ∧ Q from P ↔ Q which is incorrect. From your original assumption at 1, □¬A is false and □A is also false, so □¬A ↔ □A is true and □¬A ∧ □A is false. You don't have to use possible world semantics with modal logic if you don't want, but it is very useful for providing models and countermodels. In any event, ¬(◇A ∧ ◇¬A) is not a theorem, except in some very weird modal systems such as Triv and Ver.

I do not understand why the proof bothers saying #8 if it has said #1.  If there is a contradiction at #8, then there was also a contradiction when the  same statement was first made in #1.

@Bumble, I was saving myself some steps, I'll fix it.
